# readonly not working in the multiple autoComplete primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, autocomplete, primefaces

The `readonly` attribute of `<p:autoComplete>` does not work. I still can type text in after setting `readonly="true"`. I don't want to use `disabled="true"`, because it won't let me remove any of the selections. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Can you show related code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like a know issue (at least in 3.4.2)

[Issue 5070:    auto complete readonly but send ajax to server](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=5070)

Possible workaround :

> Render outputText or read-only inputText component instead.

[PrimeFaces Community Forum : autocomplete readonly: still send ajax](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27627)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. However, I found a work around. You can make the individual contents of the auto complete set to readonly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.getElementById('contentForm:myId_input').setAttribute("readOnly","true");
    });

    // ]]>
</script>
```

Here **myId** is the id of the autocomplete. The input box has an id **myId_input**, which is simply '_input' appended at the end.

As far as the existing values go, you can use the **select** and the **unselect** events to restrict changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's my workaround. **It looks as like as the autocomplete component**

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="ui-autocomplete ui-autocomplete-multiple">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="ui-autocomplete-multiple-container ui-widget ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.values}" var="value">
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="ui-autocomplete-token ui-state-active ui-corner-all">
                <h:outputText styleClass="ui-autocomplete-token-label" value="#{value}"/>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:repeat>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```